# 'chrome' object is undefined in AngularJS $window service

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-app

I am developing a Chrome App with AngularJS. My app uses chrome.storage so I created a wrapper in order to work with it. Code of wrapper looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('chromeStorageApi', function ($window, $q) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  return {
    set: function (obj) {
      if ('chrome' in $window && typeof  $window.chrome.storage === 'undefined') {
        return deferred.reject();
      } else {
        $window.chrome.storage.local.set(obj, function(){
          if($window.chrome.runtime.lastError !== 'undefined') {
            return deferred.reject();
          }
          deferred.resolve();
        });
      }
     ................
```

I have another service ('storageService') which has my wrapper as a dependency:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('storageService', function ($q, $rootScope, $http, chromeStorageApi) {
.......
```

The problem is that **$window** in storageService has 'chrome' object and it's possible to work with chrome.storage there but in my wrapper 'chrome' object gets 'undefined'.

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$window.chrome.storage')
```

I would like to get understanding why that happens. In one place **$window** has 'chrome' object but in another one hasn't.

Thanks.